# Android MQTT using Paho Client. Unable to receive messages

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I have a AndroidService to listen MQTT messages. Below is the code. For some reason the service is able to connect and subscribe to channel, but is unable is read messages. `messageArrived` is never called.

```
public class FollowService extends Service implements MqttCallback{

    private final IBinder localBinder = new FollowServiceBinder();
    private final String TAG = "Service";
    private MqttClient mqClient;

    public class FollowServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public FollowService getService() {
            return FollowService.this;
        }
    }

    public FollowService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return localBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            mqClient = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.46:1883", "sadfsfi", new MemoryPersistence());
            mqClient.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to client");
        }
        catch(MqttException me){
            Log.e(TAG, "MqttClient Exception Occured in on create!!!", me);
        }
    }

    @Keep
    public void beginFollowing(){
        try {
            mqClient.subscribe("test");
            Log.i(TAG, "Subscribed test");
            }
        catch (MqttException me){
            Log.e(TAG, "MqttClient Exception Occured in following!!!", me);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionLost");
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Delivered");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received update: " + topic + ":" + message.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [Eclipse Paho Android Service](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) which is dedicated to Android you can use instead of the regular `MqttClient`, it may solves your problem (if your are sure the problem is not on your MQTT server side) & some other problems you may have in the future if you want to settle an Android MQTT service :

If you want to give it a try :

in `build.gradle` :

```
compile  'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
compile  ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and in your `<application></application>` :

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
```

Here is an example `MqttHandler.java` :

```
public class MqttHandler {

    protected final static String TAG = DeviceHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * MQTT client
     */
    private MqttAndroidClient mClient = null;

    /**
     * client ID used to authenticate
     */
    protected String mClientId = "";

    /**
     * Android context
     */
    private Context mContext = null;

    /**
     * callback for MQTT events
     */
    private MqttCallback mClientCb = null;

    /**
     * callback for MQTT connection
     */
    private IMqttActionListener mConnectionCb = null;

    /**
     * Sets whether the client and server should remember state across restarts and reconnects
     */
    protected boolean mCleanSessionDefault = false;

    /**
     * Sets the connection timeout value (in seconds)
     */
    protected int mTimeoutDefault = 30;

    /**
     * Sets the "keep alive" interval (in seconds)
     */
    protected int mKeepAliveDefault = 60;

    /**
     * connection state
     */
    private boolean connected = false;

    /**
     * list of message callbacks
     */
    private List<IMessageCallback> mMessageCallbacksList = new ArrayList<>();

    private final static String SERVER_URI = "192.168.1.46";

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 1883;

    public MqttHandler(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;

        this.mClientCb = new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                connected = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < mMessageCallbacksList.size(); i++) {
                    mMessageCallbacksList.get(i).connectionLost(cause);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < mMessageCallbacksList.size(); i++) {
                    mMessageCallbacksList.get(i).messageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mMessageCallbacksList.size(); i++) {
                    mMessageCallbacksList.get(i).deliveryComplete(token);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        if (mClient == null)
            return false;
        else
            return connected;
    }

    public void connect() {

        try {
            if (!isConnected()) {

                MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();

                String serverURI = "";

                options.setCleanSession(mCleanSessionDefault);
                options.setConnectionTimeout(mTimeoutDefault);
                options.setKeepAliveInterval(mKeepAliveDefault);

                mClient = new MqttAndroidClient(mContext, "tcp://" + SERVER_URI + ":" + SERVER_PORT, mClientId);
                mClient.setCallback(mClientCb);

                mConnectionCb = new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
                        connected = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < mMessageCallbacksList.size(); i++) {
                            mMessageCallbacksList.get(i).onConnectionSuccess(iMqttToken);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
                        connected = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < mMessageCallbacksList.size(); i++) {
                            mMessageCallbacksList.get(i).onConnectionFailure(iMqttToken, throwable);
                        }
                    }
                };

                try {
                    mClient.connect(options, mContext, mConnectionCb);
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "cant connect - already connected");
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "parameters error. cant connect");
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {

        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                mClient.disconnect(mContext, mConnectionCb);

            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "cant disconnect - already disconnected");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Publish a message to MQTT server
     *
     * @param topic      message topic
     * @param message    message body
     * @param isRetained define if message should be retained on MQTT server
     * @param listener   completion listener (null allowed)
     * @return
     */
    public IMqttDeliveryToken publishMessage(String topic, String message, boolean isRetained, IMqttActionListener listener) {

        if (isConnected()) {

            MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
            mqttMessage.setRetained(isRetained);
            mqttMessage.setQos(0);

            try {
                return mClient.publish(topic, mqttMessage, mContext, listener);
            } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "cant publish message. Not connected");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to topic
     *
     * @param topic    topic to subscribe
     * @param listener completion listener (null allowed)
     * @return
     */
    public void subscribe(String topic, IMqttActionListener listener) {

        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                mClient.subscribe(topic, 0, mContext, listener);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "cant publish message. Not connected");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unsubscribe a topic
     *
     * @param topic    topic to unsubscribe
     * @param listener completion listener (null allowed)
     */
    public void unsubscribe(String topic, IMqttActionListener listener) {

        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                mClient.unsubscribe(topic, mContext, listener);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "cant publish message. Not connected");
        }
    }

    public void addCallback(IMessageCallback callback) {
        mMessageCallbacksList.add(callback);
    }
}
```

With this listener `IMessageCallback.java` :

```
public interface IMessageCallback {

    /**
     * This method is called when the connection to the server is lost.
     *
     * @param cause the reason behind the loss of connection.
     */
    void connectionLost(Throwable cause);

    /**
     * This method is called when a message arrives from the server.
     *
     * @param topic       name of the topic on the message was published to
     * @param mqttMessage the actual message
     * @throws Exception
     */
    void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception;

    /**
     * Called when delivery for a message has been completed, and all acknowledgments have been received.
     *
     * @param messageToken he delivery token associated with the message.
     */
    void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken messageToken);

    /**
     * Called when connection is established
     *
     * @param iMqttToken token for this connection
     */
    void onConnectionSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken);

    /**
     * Called when connection has failed
     *
     * @param iMqttToken token when failure occured
     * @param throwable  exception
     */
    void onConnectionFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable);

    /**
     * Called when disconnection is successfull
     *
     * @param iMqttToken token for this connection
     */
    void onDisconnectionSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken);

    /**
     * Called when disconnection failed
     *
     * @param iMqttToken token when failure occured
     * @param throwable  exception
     */
    void onDisconnectionFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable);
}
```

You can call it like that :

```
final MqttHandler mqttHandler = new MqttHandler(mContext);

mqttHandler.addCallback(new IMessageCallback() {
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        Log.v(TAG, "connectionLost");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        Log.v(TAG, "messageArrived : " + topic + " : " + new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()));
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken messageToken) {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "deliveryComplete : " + new String(messageToken.getMessage().getPayload()));
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {

        Log.v(TAG, "connection success");

        mqttHandler.subscribe("test", new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.v(TAG, "subscribe success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "subscribe failure");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.v(TAG, "connection failure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnectionSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
        Log.v(TAG, "disconnection success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnectionFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.v(TAG, "disconnection failure");
    }
});

mqttHandler.connect();
```

You can find a complete working usecase with Paho Mqtt Android client [here](https://github.com/akinaru/iotf-android/blob/master/iotf-library/src/main/java/fr/bmartel/android/iotf/handler/IotHandlerAbstr.java)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Though it is not exactly what I was looking for, it helped me resolve the issue.
I did not set callback on my client. This line solves it
`mqClient.setCallback(this);`